# Mixing Android style: Transparent and Fullscreen

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen, transparent

Anybody made this successfully? I'm trying connect two styles to get fullscreen activity with transparent background... Unfortunately it's not so easy as should be. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

If by "transparent" you mean an activity that has no background (i.e. see through to the home screen), set the activity's theme to "translucent" in the androidmanifest file:

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"

You can also set the theme in the activity's OnCreate method right before inflating the layout:
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

To make the activity less transparent, set its layout's background <strike>to a repeating 1x1 PNG image with alpha channel transparency.</strike> color to a hex value with alpha channel value between 00 and FF.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I have to mix it with fullscreen. It seems, that transparency cancels fullscreen possibility...

Comment: An activity is by nature full screen unless it is defined otherwise via a dialog theme or custom theme.  The above suggestion should work.  If not, you should probably to post your manifest.

Comment: IIRC the "Transparent" theme makes the activity look like a dialog over a transparent background, so you are correct. The "Translucent" theme however is fullscreen by default.